# unable to capture window title python

Tags: python, win32gui, pyautogui

The following code snippet should look for a window "Notes.txt - Notepad" and capture a screen-shot of that window.

```
import pyautogui
import win32gui

def screenshot(window_title="Notes.txt - Notepad"):
    if window_title:
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(window_title, None)
        if hwnd:
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
            x, y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x, y))
            x1, y1 = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x1 - x, y1 - y))
            im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, x1, y1))
            return im
        else:
            print('Window not found!')
    else:
        im = pyautogui.screenshot()
        return im


im = screenshot('Calculator')
if im:
    im.show()
```

The issues here is that no matter what I pass as window_title it always return:

```
Window not found!
```

When I `print(hwnd)` it evaluate to `0`

File title:
[image]

Comment: Replace ```FindWindow``` with ```win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, window_title)```

Comment: ```hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, window_title)```
still same issue! ```Window not found!```

Comment: I just ran it on my machine and it does what you want it to

Comment: any idea why it doesn't work on mine? Windows 10

Comment: Open Calculator, and run the script (with the change I suggested)

Comment: great it works!

Comment: @JoshuaNixon can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Got it. Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies here - `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(window_title, None)`.

Replace it with `win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, window_title)` and it should work.

[Docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html)

**EDIT:**

`win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)` should also work.